# how to send the string of click count to other page

Tags: android

i created dynamic list view ,in one row there is four buttons,what i wanted is that when i click to button no3 it goes to next page then after collecting data from that page goes on previous page and display the data.but problem is that the data should be display on the same row (i.e. some text is there), which row"s button get selected.because the list view is dynamic we not know how many such rows are there.please help me.thanks in advance

Comment: are you using adapter for list view, or creating layout from custom code?

Comment: @droid thanks for reply,i am using list view ,which using Hashmap for retrive.but problem is that at runtime i don"t know how many rows are there

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add tag ... view.addTag() ... with a unique string to each row.

Whenever you go to the next activity you save the tag somewhere, for example in the application singleton, or a static variable..whatever.

When you return, if tag != null you just have to iterate through the list and you know in which you should change the text!

Comment: thanks for reply but i am using list view dynamicaly which use hashmap for retrieve data at runtime i don"t know how many rows are there

Comment: So what? Use the the iterator key as tag or something like it. I don't get the problem of using this...